# Sylvania 9005 HB3 12V 60W, I want to know the 60W is for 1 pair or just only 1 bulb?

Tags: electrical, headlight, motors

I plan to buy a new LED headlight for my car. My car original High Beam bulb is Sylvania 9005 HB3 12V 60W ,but I confuse that the 60W is for per bulb or 1 pair? 
If 1 pair it's mean that 1 bulb is 30W?

And if I purchase the LED headlight bulb Wattage was 35W can use on my car? Any effect if I use 35W?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

An HB3 60W bulb is 60W,

so for a pair that is 2 * 60 =120W